# Load data into table after table is loaded - ngx-datatable

Tags: angular, angular6, ngx-datatable

I have a page with a dropdown and a ngx-datatable.

I page loads the dropdown and the table and depending on what the user selects, the table loads the relevant data.

Problem I'm having is the table is loading, but isn't showing the columns/rows, [but it does have a count of how many things it should be showing which is odd.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MSl3Q.png)

Relevant code:

```
  @ViewChild(DatatableComponent) table: DatatableComponent;
  columns = [];
  rows = [];

  // The dropdown kicks off a service call which is passed to this
  loadTableData(serviceCall: Observable<any>) {
    serviceCall.subscribe(data => {
      if (data.length === 0 || !data) {
        return;
      }
      this.setColumns(data[0]);
      data.forEach(rowData => {
        this.rows.push(rowData);
      });
    });
  }

  setColumns(dataObj: object) {
    Object.keys(dataObj).forEach(key => {
      this.columns.push(key);
    });
  }
```

And the html for the datatable:

```
<ngx-datatable #table 
  class="material"
  [columns]="columns"
  [columnMode]="'force'"
  [scrollbarH]="true"
  [headerHeight]="50"
  [footerHeight]="50"
  [rowHeight]="'auto'"
  [limit]="5"
  [rows]="rows">
</ngx-datatable>
```

I logged the rows/columns and they both have the right data. I think it's something to do with that table loading in first, and then me trying to fill it with data.

The data structure from the service is similar to (with a lot more rows):

```
[
 {'id': '1', 'name': 'Joe', 'job': 'window washer'},
 {'id': '2', 'name': 'Bob', 'job': 'fireman'}
]
```

Comment: can you log the structure data which you are receiving from service call..?

Comment: Add the data structure @MukulSharma

Comment: In the service subscribe I'm calling this.setColumns(data[0]); which will get all the keys and set the columns equal to that. I've included the setColumns function above.

Comment: i thing u are wrong ....check with console.log(data[0]) what exactly you are receving

Comment: It printed out the first object in the array as expected.

Comment: You were partially right. I was getting the data correctly but the columns were being set wrong. Columns expects and array of objects each having a key name.

Comment: Ok great..is that working now

Comment: Thanks for the questions which led me to look more carefully at those columns =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Leaving this up because I realized I didn't read their example code closely enough and was being dumb. Couple of problems here that I fixed:

1. I was defining the columns wrong, it takes in a list of objects with each one having the key 'name' and it's value being the column name
2. You can't push onto the rows/columns like I was, need to set them all at once otherwise it doesn't load that data

Fixed setColumns:

```
  setColumns(dataObj: object) {
    this.columns = Object.keys(dataObj).map(name => {
      return { name };
    });
  }
```

Fixed setting the rows:

```
  loadTableData(serviceCall: Observable<any>) {
    serviceCall.subscribe(data => {
      if (data.length === 0 || !data) {
        return;
      }
      this.setColumns(data[0]);
      this.rows = data;
    });
  }
```